# O que são variáveis SMARTY em CMS?

Tags: php, aplicação-web, cms

Boa noite, gostaria de saber o que são variáveis smarty, fiz uma busca na internet mas não ficou muito claro... Talvez eu só não tenha ido no local certo.
Espero que possam me ajudar.

Links de pesquisa:
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/what.is.smarty.tpl
http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/pt_BR/language.variables.tpl

O que eu entendi?
Na realidade eu me confundi, pois ele não explicou direito o que é, e além de tudo disse que são variáveis globais. Ai nos links é explicado que são templates para php, ai eu me perdi.

Comment: O ideal é mostrar os links que pesquisou e um breve resumo do que entendeu (ou não). É só [edit] a pergunta para acrescentar detalhes.

Comment: [Mesmo se você não entender inglês é possivel que entenda apenas olhando o código do cara.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5xLfvY8upsQ) Basicamente smarty é um sistema de template onde você pode gerar HTML com uma sintaxe mais simples(questionável) do que usando php puro.